# Stuck in Loading user data

Tags: jelastic

I'm using Jelastic with Flow AppEngine in Switzerland to host some applications and just recently after changing a configuration file (and hitting Save) the environment became unresponsive from an admin panel perspective. It loads all fine from the front-end but I don't think my configuration took place as I didn't have a chance to reload the service (NGINX) after having touched the config.

The behavior I see is that right after logging in to the administration panel, the loader keeps on spinning with the "Loading user data..." message and never finishes. The panel I login to is: https://app.appengine.flow.ch which seems to be using the latest Jelastic release.

**UPDATE:**
After a long time waiting, it's now moved to "Get environments..." and it's currently stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a platform error. Recommend that you contact your hosting provider for help to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

On that day (29.Dec 2013), there was a routing issue wich caused that.
It has been (already) fixed at the same day.

For future requests, feel free to contact us directly via help @ innofield.com

Cheers,
Bojan